# Discord.py - bot doesnt answer when someone mentions him

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

Im trying to do when someone mentions a bot in a channel, the bot sends the user a random message but none of the things i have tried worked. (discord.py)

```
channel = 797224597443051611

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    chat = bot.get_channel(797224597443051611)
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(msg):
        await chat.send(msg.author.mention + " " + random.choice(text))
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

I tried also this method but it doesnt work too.

```
channel = 797224597443051611

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(msg):
        await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " " + random.choice(text))
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
```

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: No, everything works fine but the bot just doesnt react.

Comment: The first code should work totally fine unless there's no problem with `text` variable.

Comment: Where are you declaring `channel = 797224597443051611` exactly? Try doing so inside the `on_message` function.

Comment: It doesnt work for some reason and i know it should, i tried the method with channel but it doesnt work too.

Comment: Are you simply wanting your bot to answer commands when mentioned?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon No, i want the bot to answer with random message when someone mentions him with @ bot to have some kind of conversation with the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer for your question. I've included more code for more context.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
       return
   mention = f'<@!{client.user.id}>'
   if str(message.content).startswith(mention):
       await message.channel.send('Your message... Testing')
```

This should be what you're looking for. If you want a random response, just change the send message to a random item from a list or a random line from a text doc.

I will edit the answer to include a random response from a list if need be.

Comment: I tried your method:

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
   mention = f'<@!{bot.user.id}>'
   if str(msg.content).startswith(mention):
       await msg.channel.send('Your message... Testing')

But it still doesnt work, i thought that it has to do something with that im using:
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") so i changed it to:
bot = discord.Client() but still it doesnt work.

Comment: I'll re-write my answer with some more code that might resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes it works now, also i find out that it works even when i attached it to another event, dont know why but finally im able to move on, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for it in the message event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    mention  = f'<@!{client.user.id}>'
    if str(message.content).startswith(mention):
        await message.channel.send('Your message for the reply here...')
```